# ionic 4 ZBar scanner performance issues

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, zbar

I am using native ZBar plugin for ionic 4 because of better performance over ionic native barcode scanner. Zbar scanner scan does not always scan the barcode correctly. I want to make it reliable and want it to perform better. from ionic I can give only these options

```
{
    text_title: "OPTIONAL Title Text - default = 'Scan QR Code'", // Android only
    text_instructions: "OPTIONAL Instruction Text - default = 'Please point your camera at the QR code.'", // Android only
    camera: "front" || "back" // defaults to "back"
    flash: "on" || "off" || "auto" // defaults to "auto". See Quirks
    drawSight: true || false //defaults to true, create a red sight/line in the center of the scanner view.
}
```

how can I make it better?

Comment: I am using ionic native barcode scanner and it working very fast.

Comment: I tried native but that takes approximately 7 to 8 seconds to complete scan. is it accurate?Did you put an extra effort in performance tuning?@Khurshid Ansari

Comment: No i did nothing for performance. I am just using barcode scanner. it get scanned very quickly from far distance. I have tested in small device to high end device.

Comment: Thanks for review I ll try that @KhurshidAnsari

Comment: I would suggest checking in different devices. There are [issues raised](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues) for this plugin related to different behaviors in different devices.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh could be the reason for bad performance.. any recommendations?

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari keep the code with **barcodescanner** only and create a production build. Test that build in different devices and notices if you see different behavior(speed in your case).